# Why is CSSRule empty when read from a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The [`CSSRule` DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) contains constants corresponding to each type of CSS rule. The type of a rule can be tested with statements like

```
someRule.type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE
```

I am building a Firefox add-on using the SDK. When read from this add-on's content script file, `CSSRule` exists but is empty.

```
console.log("CSSRule is " + CSSRule);
for(var key in CSSRule) {
    console.log('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + CSSRule[key]);
}
console.log("CSSRule.STYLE_RULE is " + CSSRule.STYLE_RULE);
```

outputs

```
CSSRule is [object CSSRule]
CSSRule.STYLE_RULE is undefined
```

When executing the same from a `script` inside a page, or from the Firefox console, the output is as I expect, with `CSSRule.STYLE_RULE` set to `1`.

When executing from a pageMod `contentScript` instead of a external content script file, `CSSRule` is `{}` instead.

Waiting for the page to finish loading, and using `window.CSSRule` instead of `CSSRule`, do not change the behaviour.

I have tested this on Firefox 45.0.1 (current release) and today's nightly (48.01a 2016-04-10), on OS X.

Why is `CSSRule` empty? How can I access those constants, other than setting them manually to the correct values?

Comment: which FF version? have you tried on nightly?

Comment: @the8472 45.0.1, same behaviour on nightly. Have edited the question.

Comment: if it works, just run your code as a script on the page instead of directly from the extension.

Comment: @dandavis: You mean use the addon to inject a `script` element into the page, and run from there?

Comment: @Leopold: yes, that's exactly what i meant. it's worked for me in the past and it lets you live-update the code easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [bug 898764](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=898764). Extension scripts run in a sandbox that provides [xray vision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision) on the content.

That means properties defined by the untrusted web content are not visible but pristine instances of all IDL-defined properties and constants *should* be visible.

For the time being the following might serve as a workaround, but would expose your code to values potentially changed or removed by content:

```
if(!("STYLE_RULE" in CSSRule)) {
   window.CSSRule = unsafeWindow.CSSRule
}
```

> if it works, just run your code as a script on the page instead of directly from the extension. – dandavis

This is not recommended for security reasons and might not pass addon review if you want to publish it.

Comment: `unsafeWindow.CSSRule` has the correct value, thanks. For security reasons I'll use the constant values (such as `1` for a `STYLE_RULE`) instead.

Comment: According to [bug 898764](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=898764) CSSRule simply is not implemented in terms of WebIDL yet thus it doesn't get xrayed properly. Once that's fixed it should work in addons too.